# Uso di “ora di”

Tags: adverbs

Sento e leggo ogni tanto locuzioni temporali introdotte da “ora di X” nel senso di “giunto X”. Per esempio “ora di sera, Gianni era tornato a casa” nel senso appunto di “giunta la sera, Gianni era tornato a casa” o “a sera Gianni era ormai tornato a casa”. (È una costruzione piuttosto simile a uno degli usi dell'inglese *by*: “by evening, Gianni...”)
Lo stesso può valere per altre indicazioni di tempo: “ora di giugno”, “ora di mezzanotte” e così via.

Alle mie orecchie non sembra un uso del tutto standard, bensì forse regionale (settentrionale?). Fonti alla mano, me lo sapreste confermare o smentire?

(Purtroppo è particolarmente difficile compiere ricerche testuali, perché “ora di” compare in molte altre costruzioni: “ora di pranzo”, “ora di Mosca” etc. E persino “ora di sera”, per esempio, può venire da altre costruzioni, come “Chi può bussare a quest'ora di sera?”)

Comment: Potresti indicare dove hai letto questa forma?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: Qua e là, dove capitava. Non in testi “d'autore”, che altrimenti costituirebbero già una parziale risposta alla mia domanda.

Comment: Questa frase, tratta da un [articolo in un giornale di Venezia](http://nuovavenezia.gelocal.it/venezia/cronaca/2015/12/02/news/e-un-far-west-ora-di-sera-temiamo-pure-gli-adolescenti-1.12552691), sarebbe un buon esempio? «È un Far West, ora di sera temiamo pure gli adolescenti».

Comment: Anche su questo sito web, http://vivalamamma.tgcom24.it/2014/09/si-torna-a-scuola-ecco-i-consigli-di-tata-lucia/, si trova: "In ogni caso, alzandosi alle sette del mattino, ora di sera i bambini saranno già molto stanchi." Si tratta di un programma della TV?

Comment: @Charo Entrambi sono buoni esempi (e sì, il secondo riporta un'intervista effettuata durante un talk show, *Mattino 5*)

Comment: @Charo: Il secondo esempio rientra esattamente nella costruzione a cui si riferisce la mia domanda (“...per quando arriva la sera i bambini saranno già stanchi”), mentre il primo no. Lì l'uso di “ora” è semplicemente sinonimo di “attualmente” (= “Prima, la sera, eravamo tranquilli, mentre attualmente temiamo etc.”). Vedi anche la risposta di Simone Marini e il mio commento.

Comment: Capisco, @DaG, grazie!

Answer (score 2):

Non credo che la locuzione abbia una specifica connotazione regionale, la considererei più una forma colloquiale universale. Come sottolineato da Andrea, essa deriva da una parziale elisione, che porta a sottointendere una parte della frase. Non sono però d'accordo che la forma completa sia "All'ora di". Mentre considero corretta la frase

> All'ora di cena molte reti trasmettono il telegiornale

Che vuol dire che molti TG vengono mandati in onda ad un orario a cui molte persone cenano (19:30-20:30), togliendo "all"

> Ora di cena, molte reti trasmettono il telegiornale

Non è assolutamente corretta o sensata, né l'ho mai sentita dire. Trovo invece che la forma completa sia "giunta l'ora di"

> *Giunta l'ora di* cena non avevo ancora finito i compiti
>
> *Ora di* cena, non avevo ancora finito i compiti

Vuole dire che, arrivato il momento di una certa cosa, successe il fatto specificato nel resto della frase. Infatti, espandendo il tuo esempio aggiugnendo *giunta l'ora di*, come hai fatto tu, si ottiene il costrutto correto, mentre aggiungendo *all'ora di* si ottiene una frase a mio parere cacofonica e scorretta

> All'ora di sera, Gianni era tornato a casa

Non esiste "l'ora di sera", ma con "ora di sera" si intende "per il momento in cui si fece sera".

Ribadisco che, in conclusione, la trovo una forma sicuramente colloquiale, formalmente scorretta e molto usata nel parlare comune, ma senza una specifica connotazione regionale.

In quanto al tuo altro esempio, "ora di Mosca", la trovo una cosa completamente differente. La forma completa sarebbe

> Secondo l'ora di Mosca

Con il significato di "seguendo il fuso orario di Mosca". L'abbreviazione non è per niente considerata scorretta, ed è comunemente usata dai giornalisti. Qualora ci fosse un particolare accadimento nella capitale russa, i giornalisti riporterebbero "Alle 11:32, ora di Mosca", intendendo che a Greenwich erano le 8:32. Allo stesso modo, il GMT viene chiamato in Italiano "Ora di Greenwich".

Invece, "Ora di Giugno" non l'ho mai sentito, e mi pare molto scorretto. Anche se in questo costrutto "ora" non sta per l'unità di misurazione del tempo, sta comunque per "momento", e associarlo ad un lasso in larga scala e potenzialmente a grande distanza come un mese è inappropriato. Al posto di dire

> Ora di Giugno, le mie Surfinie si erano seccate

Direi

> A Giugno le mie Surfinie erano secche
>
> Arrivò Giugno e le mie Surfinie erano già secche

O, molto molto colloquiale

> Tempo Giugno e le mie Surfinie erano secche

Non mi viene in mente nessun esempio per cui non esista alternativa a "ora di", il quale è a mio parere scorretto pure nel parlato corrente.

Comment: Grazie. Per chiarire, “ora di Mosca” era un esempio dei “falsi positivi” che si trovano cercando solo “ora di” in Google Books o altri corpora.

Comment: @DaG Ah, capisco. Pardon, non avevo bene inteso il senso dell'ultimo pezzo.

Comment: In effetti non hai tutti i torti sul fatto che *all'ora di* non vada sempre bene. Possiamo dire forse che una forma corretta sarebbe *fattasi sera*?

Comment: Forma sicuramente corretta ma molto innaturale ed altisonante, a mio avviso. Potresti trovarla scritta in un romanzo ma difficilmente mi aspetterei di sentirla da una persona qualunque. Di uso più comune è forse *fatta sera*, anche se è meno corretta.

Answer (score 1):

> bensì forse regionale (settentrionale?)

Abito nell'Italia settentrionale (Veneto) e non ho mai sentito usare questa locuzione. Mi sembra anzi quasi *fastidiosa* da sentire. A mio parere non è una forma corretta in italiano, sembra che sia stata omessa una parte. Avrebbe più senso se fosse:

> All'ora di sera, Gianni [...]

**Nota:** Ciò mi ricorda un'altra locuzione poco corretta (ma più diffusa e più tollerata), cioè "Settimana scorsa":

> Settimana scorsa sono andato al mare.

La forma corretta sarebbe:

> La settimana scorsa sono andato al mare.

Comment: Grazie mille per la tua testimonianza sul Veneto. Quanto alla tua opinione di fastidio e di scorrettezza, quello che cerco sono fonti un po' più oggettive (vocabolari o testi che riportino questa locuzione, o linguisti che l'abbiano analizzata).

Comment: Capisco, però per essere indicata nei testi o nei vocabolari dovrebbe essere una forma corretta. Oppure una forma scorretta ma molto famosa. Tu dove l'hai trovata?

Comment: Curioso: sono veneto pure io e l'ho sentita e anche usata.

Comment: Anche in Lombardia 'ora di sera' è una forma utilizzata; purtroppo non ho riferimenti oggettivi ma si tratta di una forma nota per quanto di uso poco comune. Una precisazione: ho scritto 'ora di sera' perchè è l'unica forma che ricordi di aver mai sentito. Non ricordo di aver mai sentito o usato 'ora di mezzanotte', 'ora di giugno', solo 'ora di sera'.

Comment: Anch'io sono veneto (circa a metà strada tra Mestre e Treviso) e l'ho sentita e usata.

Comment: Ok quindi sembra essere usata nelle stesse regioni in cui si è diffusa la dubbia forma "settimana scorsa". Resta il fatto che grammaticalmente sembra fare acqua da tutte le parti.

Comment: Veneto pure io e la sento ed uso

Comment: Bene, ma ribadisco... un conto è usarla, un conto è che sia italiano. Noi veneti spesso parliamo un italiano che è a dir poco *inondato* di espressioni dubbie di derivazione dialettale.

Answer (score -1):

In Toscana questa locuzione viene usata abbastanza spesso, almeno a Pistoia dove vivo.
Io la uso proprio come nell'articolo indicato da @Charo. In questo caso "ora" significa adesso, negli ultimi tempi/giorni e "di sera" indica il vero tempo in cui si svolgono le azioni, che vengono quindi comparate a quello che accadeva nel passato.

> È un Far West, ora di sera temiamo pure gli adolescenti

Significa che negli ultimi tempi, la sera, gli adolescenti sono diventati pericolosi, mentre nel passato questo non era vero.

Altri esempi:

> "Ora di sera non riesco più a guardare la televisione da quando è nato mio figlio"
>
> "Ora di Maggio il biancospino ha già fiorito. Tutta colpa del riscaladamento globale".

Comment: Grazie, ma è una costruzione diversa da quella a cui mi riferisco io. Se capisco bene, quella che dici tu si riferisce a situazioni recenti ma abituali e si potrebbe parafrasare con qualcosa come “attualmente, di sera (o giugno o...) succede la tal cosa”. Invece quella di cui parlo nella domanda si riferisce per lo più al passato, a eventi specifici e si potrebbe parafrasare come “per quando era arrivata la sera (giugno etc.), era successa/stava succedendo la tal cosa”. Cf. il mio esempio “ora di sera [= giunta la sera], Gianni era tornato a casa”.

Comment: Simone, la tua risposta (cioè "adesso, di sera") non corrisponde al significato dell'espressione che si suppone nella domanda. È totalmente diverso.